# Execution is not going inside a function in a angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in calling a function `checkLogin` of a controller. 
I am using the value returned by `checkLogin` to hide/show with `ng-show`. When i check by debugging the execution is happening until function call and later on it is just skipping to execute that function so i am not getting any thing in return please see the following code and let me know if anything is wrong out here..

**The function i am  calling is *checkLogin()*** from the LoginController please observe that function

**Angular Module**

```
'use strict';

var mainApp=angular.module('MainModule',['ngRoute']);
mainApp.constant('encrypt','');
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl : "index.html",
    controller : 'LoginController'
})
.when("/loginpage",{
    templateUrl : "ataclient/login/loginpage.html",
    controller : 'LoginController'})
.when("/registration",{
    templateUrl: "ataclient/register/register.html",
    controller: 'RegistrationController'
});
});
```

**Angular Controller**

```
   'use strict';

    function LoginController(encrypt,$http,$scope,$location){

        $scope.userName = "";
        $scope.password ="";
        $scope.loginstatus=true;
        $scope.data="";
        $scope.loginSubmit = function(){
            alert("inside login submit");
            if($scope.userName && $scope.password){ 
                $http({
                    url:'http://localhost:8080/com/rest/user/login',
                    method:"POST",
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    },
                    data : {
                        "userName" : $scope.userName,
                        "passwd" : $scope.password
                    }
                }).then(function(response){$scope.data = response;});
                if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){
                    encrypt = $scope.data.data.encryptedkey ;
                    $scope.loginstatus = false;
                    console.log($scope.loginstatus);
                    alert(encrypt);
                }
            }
        };
        $scope.checkLogin = function(){
            alert("inside checkLogin");
            if(encrypt != null){
                return false;
            }
            else
                {
                return true;
                }
        };

        this.login=function(){
            alert("for u in sss");
            $http({
                url:'http://localhost:8080/com/browsers',
                method:"GET",
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'SessionId': 1478785782179
                }
            }).
            then(function(Response){$scope.data=Response;});
        };
    }

    LoginController.$inject = ['encrypt','$http' ,'$scope','$location'];

    mainApp.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
```

and the html piece of code using to call is 
**html piece**

```
     <form  ng-submit="loginSubmit()" ng-controller = "LoginController">

            <div class="col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xl-12 text-center" id="logintitle">Login Here</div> 

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2   col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-8 col-xl-offset-2 form-group">
                <label for="UserName"> User Name</label>
                <input type="UserName" ng-model="userName" placeholder="Enter UserName" class="form-control" id="username" aria-describedby="UserNamehelp">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2   col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-8 col-xl-offset-2 form-group">
                <label for="UserName"> User Name</label>
                <input type="Password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control" id="password" aria-describedby="PassWordHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-4">
                <button ng-show ="checkLogin()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit {{data.data.encryptedkey}}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-xl-4 col-xl-offset-2 ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="forgot">forgot</button>
            </div>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your javascript console for errors. In fact replace all those `alert()` and `console.log()` calls with `$log.debug()` calls.

I think your problem is the line:

```
if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){
```

This line is not inside the success handler for `$http` so it will be executed immiediately, before you have assigned anything to `$scope.data` which means you will get an error when you try to access `"".data.encryptedkey`. Then when the data arrives you do nothing with the resulting assignment to `$scope.data`.

Move that `if` inside the success function, and also add in a handler for when the call fails.

```
$http({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/com/rest/user/login',
    method:"POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    data : {
        "userName" : $scope.userName,
        "passwd" : $scope.password
    }
}).then(successFn);

function successFn (response){
    $scope.data = response;
    if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){
         encrypt = $scope.data.data.encryptedkey ;
         $scope.loginstatus = false;
    }
}
```

The `checkLogin()` function will only be called when angular realises that something has changed. It should be called once when the `$http` request completes, but as your code isn't setting `encrypt` at that point it will still return `false`. After that, unless something else changes there is no reason for angular to call it again.

Actually you would be better to set a flag in the model and check that directly from the html rather than calling a function each time. Avoid calling functions from directives whenever possible as they get called every time anything changes: if you can pre-compute the result and just store that it will usually be better.

Comment: Hi Duncan, my problem is not with the "loginSubmit" function it is with the "checkLogin()" function..the execution is not going inside this function ....if what you said is related to "checkLogin()" fucntion  then please elobarate it ..

Comment: @Sud, I've elaborated. You need to fix the problem I pointed out and then see if your function gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value to the constant provider `encrypt`

```
mainApp.constant('encrypt','');
...
if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){
  encrypt = $scope.data.data.encryptedkey;
...
```

The name of the provider implies it should not be changed, I would suggest using the [value provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe) instead.

Your real problem, as Duncan has mentioned, is that your `if` block is outside of your http response block

```
...
}).then(function(response){$scope.data = response;});
  if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){  //<--- problem!
     encrypt = $scope.data.data.encryptedkey;
...
```

change this to the following and you'll be a step close to success~~

```
...
}).then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response;});
  if($scope.data.data.encryptedkey != null ){
     encrypt = $scope.data.data.encryptedkey;
     $scope.loginstatus = false;
     console.log($scope.loginstatus);
     alert(encrypt);
  }
});
...
```